# Random method named cv_member_url()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a total noob to rails and I'm trying to understand a project I'm working on. I've found a method named cv_member_url in one of the views, but I can't for the life of me figure out where it is defined... One thing I do know about rails is that it is a very flexible language so it could be some sort of gem creating this method.

Any ideas where this method may have come from? (or better yet, how I can add others)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are named routes which are automatically defined based on what you have in routes.rb. *_url should be used in the controller, and *_path should be used in the views. Here's some more info from the [official rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a model called CvMember? If so, the method is probably a named route for that model. See here for more info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls

To see all your named routes, you can run

```
rake routes
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can run this in development: You should put a breakpoint on it and step inside. Most likely it is dynamically defined or maybe in plugin.